# Pandas dataframe limit using xlwings?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, xlwings

I am pulling data from an excel sheet using xlwings and pandas however, there are 3063 rows in the sheet but pandas only pulls in 3000 rows. How can I pull in all 3063 rows?

```
Code:
wb = xw.Book("Sheet.xlsb", read_only=True, update_links=False)
sheet = wb.sheets["Sheet1"]
df = sheet.range('A3').options(pd.DataFrame, 
                             header=1,
                             index=False, 
                             expand='table').value
wb.close()
```

Comment: I'm guessing its because the table is that many rows

Comment: Agreeing with @moken... You are starting from cell `A3`, which is on row 3.  So if row 3 is a header row, and the total rows used is 3063, then 4:3063 will be your data, i.e. 3000 rows which is the same as the DataFrame.